# Why Application user.id is different from _db.Users id

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm new in ASP.Net and working with identityDb
I want to know why the id not the same ? [image: _db.User ID for the same user]

[image: the Application User ID]

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> ResendEmail(ApplicationUser user)
        {
            ApplicationUser currentUseer = _db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == user.Id)
}
```

Comment: these are two different variables. the passed in applicationUser is different than Identity User. So the question is, how/why are you passing  a user to this method, where/how is this being populated and why is it different.

Comment: are you calling the ResendEmail Action from your code?! or by an HTTP call? you should not call it from your code. also, for resend email you must only get user's email, not an Id!